# Understanding after_update callback in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have a Rails object with `after_update` callback that sends a record to a queue. And the problem is that I noticed sometimes the queue is being processed faster than the object is actually being updated.

My question: is `after_update` called not after the object updating ended, but when it started? What callback I need if I want to do something with it only **after** update is successful?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`after_save`, `after_create`, `after_update` are called within the transaction block, so they will be executed before executing the SQL statement.

If you want to do something when the statement execution is completed, you should use [after_commit](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit) callback.

Answer (score 6):

If you consult the Rails documentation you will find a lot of callbacks you can use. The best for this job might be "after_commit":

This is straight from the Rails Docs (link at the bottom)

```
3.1 Creating an Object

before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback

3.2 Updating an Object

before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_update
around_update
after_update
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback

3.3 Destroying an Object

before_destroy
around_destroy
after_destroy
```

Rails DOcs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html