# Rails after_save and after_commit gotcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`after_save` is called when the record is saved (but before it's committed). While `after_create` is called, well, after database transaction has been committed.

Other than this post http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-couple-callback-gotchas-and-a-rails-5-fix/ which explain Sidekiq job can't find an object because the code is running before the object is committed, what are other gotchas that I need to know in order to decide wheter `after_create` or `after_commit` is more suitable to be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding after\_update callback in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310768/understanding-after-update-callback-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid Sidekiq being 'too fast', as you're describing, the solution that I most commonly see is to use `after_commit`.

This has one large disadvantage - If you're updating something in the model, the `after_commit` hook will run again. Make sure this will never happen.

See the example:
You're creating a `TextMessage` and saving this to the database with `status='unsent'`, and in an `after_commit` hook, you're adding a SidekiqJob for sending this to your SMS Gateway, via an API.
This API returns an ID, for tracking it remotely, and you then update this to your TextMessage from earlier. This will trigger a resend of the TextMessage.

Of course, `after_commit` also responds to `on: :update` and `on: create`, like `before_save` etc does.

Here, you could, in the job, ensure that the job is `unsent` before, but this may still trigger a resend, even though you've ensured this.

It's easy to make infinite loops in this, and it may cost you quite a lot if you're not careful.