# saved_change_to_attribute? always returns false when called inside method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have an `after_update` callback in an `ActiveRecord` model to notify an external service. This should only be called if a couple of attributes are being updated. So I encapsulated the `saved_change_to_attribute?` calls in a method that is then used in the callback filter:

```
after_update :tell_service!, if: :update_for_service?

def update_for_service?
  saved_change_to_name? ||
  saved_change_to_city? 
end
```

Now `update_for_service?` always returns `false` and I don't understand why.

In the console:

```
> p = Person.last
> p.name = 'Tom'
> p.save
true
> p.saved_change_to_name?
true
> p.update_for_service?
false
```

What is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you put a `binding.pry` inside your `update_for_service?`?

Comment: Do you have other callbacks on this model that could be interfering? I set up a model identical to yours and it worked exactly as you'd expect. Try making a model from scratch or pick a very simple model and try your code in that model. The code definitely should work.

Comment: any solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to when `after_update` runs in the callback lifecycle. [This answer by pan.goth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43310869/203130) explains:

> `after_save`, `after_create`, `after_update` are called within the transaction block, so they will be executed before executing the SQL statement.
>
> If you want to do something when the statement execution is completed, you should use [after_commit](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit) callback.

Comment: this is generally true - although I'm still having `saved_change_to_attribute?` return false in a method just like OP